# Delphi Boolean Return Function Hint: Value assigned to '' never used?

Tags: arrays, delphi, function, boolean

I have

```
playerIds : Array[0..500] of string;

function isPlayerMob(check : string): boolean;
var
    i : integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to 500 do
    begin
        if ((playerIds[i] <> '') and (playerIds[i] = check)) then
        begin
            result := true;
        end;
    end;
    result := false;
end;
```

I get the Warning

```
Hint: Value assigned to 'isPlayerMob' never used
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?
The error is for the

> result := true;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have told you, the value your loop is assigning to `Result` is being discarded because you are not exiting the function before the final assignment to `Result`, so it does not matter what the loop assigns.

You could assign the Result with an initial value and then reassign it as needed, or you could simply `Exit` after you have assigned your desired value:

```
function isPlayerMob(check : string): boolean;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 500 do
  begin
    if ((playerIds[i] <> '') and (playerIds[i] = check)) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit; // <-- add this
    end;
  end;
  Result := False; // <-- only performed if the loop does not find a match
end;
```

Or, if you are using a recent Delphi version:

```
function isPlayerMob(check : string): boolean;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 500 do
  begin
    if ((playerIds[i] <> '') and (playerIds[i] = check)) then
      Exit(True); // <-- sets Result and exits at the same time
  end;
  Result := False; // <-- only performed if the loop does not find a match
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

This hint is because your always are assigning the `false` value to the function. no matter if the value if found in the loop.

try this

```
function isPlayerMob(const check : string): boolean;
var
    i : integer;
begin
    result := false;
    for i := 0 to 500 do
        if ((playerIds[i] <> '') and (playerIds[i] = check)) then
        begin
          result := true;
          break;
        end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of using the `Exit;` command in the middle, this seems better.

Comment: in this *specific case*, `break` and `exit` will work in the same way. Aslo depending of you delphi version you can write `if ((playerIds[i] <> '') and (playerIds[i] = check)) then exit(true);`

Comment: Exit is much better here. Use break and you wonder what else the function might do. This is a function that does not modify state and whose sole task is to evaluate Result. Once is has definitively set Result it should quit.

Comment: A real nice solution would be using a `while` or `repeat..until` loop with a proper exit condition. (Somewhat like `while ((i <= 500) and (not Result))`. In this case the iterator must be incremented manually of course.)

Comment: @mg30rg That would not be a nice solution. The nice solution is to use exit as it was intended. as demonstrated by Remy. Wild use of `exit` inside procedures that mutate state can be a bad thing. Using exit to terminate from a non-mutating function as soon as the result is known is the intended use case of exit. Of course, the best solution would be if the language had a real `return` statement like C, C++, C#, Java, D, Python etc. But it's too late for that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Next time you will advice to use `goto`?

Comment: @mg30rg Please don't put words in my mouth. I'm advising on the use of exit in one very specific case. Read again what I have said. It should be used in non-mutating functions at the earliest opportunity, that is as soon as the function return value is known. Trying to avoid using exit and instead using while loops that test the return value leads to more complex code that it less efficient. If the language had a real `return` statement then things would be different. But it does not and so using exit in this way is the best option.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan using `break`, `exit` and `goto` are the marks of bad (unreadable) code design. In this specific case my solution is as satisfying as using `exit`, and if you will ever have more code after the loop it must be put in a conditional block which depends on the value of Result unless you wish to utilize it - when it is really pointless to use Exit.

Comment: @mg30rg You might find using a loop with an extra time consuming test satisfying. I find it vile and I never accept such code. I find your comment *if you will ever have more code after the loop* curious. I am specifically talking about non-mutating functions. The only code you ever have in the functions that I describe is dedicated to finding result. I never like dogma and I sense that the reluctance to use `exit` is dogma. Even the usually awful `goto` has its place. There are a tiny number of problems that are best solved with `goto`. In those cases, use it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So you are telling that testing inside the loop core (with no condition, so always performed) is more time consuming than testing at the loop exit condition?

Comment: @mg30rg Your loop includes a test on the value of `Result` on each and every iteration. That's not present in the versions that use `exit`, or even those that use `break`. It's not likely that the performance will be an issue, but I don't see the point in making the code more verbose and less efficient. What do you gain in doing so?

Comment: @mg30rg It's not easier to read. There's more of it, and more branching and logic to parse. Even after years and years of experience, nobody find `while ((i <= 500) and (not Result))` trivial to parse. Everyone has to think carefully about it. That's because it has branching and logic. You have to think, "should it be `and` or should it be `or`. And you have to think "should there be a `not`, or should there not be".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand your point although I do not agree. I think a basic logical step is easier to follow than a code that can't be read sequentially. But - you know - "de gustibus non est disputandum".

Comment: @mg30rg Yes, matters of taste. I cannot argue against that point. All I can say is that I have been able to train myself to read the exit based code without stretching my brain, but have never succeeding in doing the same with `while` loops. The logic in the test of a `while` loop is always a problem for me. Perhaps it's me.

Answer (score 2):

Your function as written will always execute the final `Result := false;` line, and therefore the value assigned inside the loop will always be discarded.

Change your function instead to initialize the result first:

```
function isPlayerMob(check : string): boolean;
var
    i : integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  for i := 0 to 500 do
  begin
    if ((playerIds[i] <> '') and (playerIds[i] = check)) then
    begin
      Result := true;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In Delphi 2009 and higher, the `Result := True; Exit;` lines can be replaced with simply `Exit(True);` instead.

Comment: Thanks I thought Result would automatically return.

Comment: If you want to immediately exit from the function and return result, you can use `Exit(value)`, in your case `Exit(TRUE)` or `Exit(FALSE)`

Comment: @MarkoPaunovic that is true, but depends of the Delphi version.

Comment: Yes. Do you maybe know when `Exit(value)` was introduced?

Comment: You can also call `Exit` without a parameter after assigning `Result` separately.

Comment: The optional `Exit` parameter was introduced in Delphi 2009.

Comment: Where did you read that that's how assigning to `Result` behaved, Sspoke? It's useful to be aware of where bad information originates so we know to be wary of it in the future.

Comment: @RobKennedy, at times I have seen people mixing up the c `return` statement with delphi `Result`.